# What does " out of extreme urgency" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have a definition of "desperate":

> To act desperate means to appear to do something out of extreme urgency or as a last resort, when you feel as if you have no choice,

What does " out of extreme urgency" mean in this sentence? Does it mean "keep you from extreme urgency"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example

> out of

has the meaning

> because of
>   *because of extreme urgency*

*Extreme urgency* can mean *very quickly*, which is necessary when someone is desperate.

It can also mean *very important*

> This is a matter of extreme urgency.

Answer (score 0):

It means *because of*, or *due to*, or *for reasons of*:

[out of](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/out%20of)  (definition 2)

used as a function word to indicate origin, source, or cause: "a remarkable colt out of an ordinary mare", "built out of old lumber", "fled out of fear"

Answer (score 0):

The preposition [*out of*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/out_of) has more meanings than what you would expect from *out* + *of*. In this case, the meaning is:

> With the motivation of.

Usually it is used with emotions (*I insulted him out of anger*) and states (*he stole bread out of hunger*).